# Error in using int() when importing data from .rtf file

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I am new to coding and might be missing something here. I am trying to import a .rtf file, but my code errors at the x.append(int(row[0])) with the following message:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

Here is my code:

```
with open('example.rtf', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in plots: 
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(int(row[1]))
```

For reference, here is my data:
1,5
2,3
3,4
4,7
5,4
6,3
7,5
8,7
9,4
10,4

Comment: Empty string would probably produce `array index out of range` when trying to get `row[1]`

Comment: You are trying to open an `rtf` file as `csv` file. That would probably fail. I don't know if there are any `rtf` reader around for python. But in general, you would want to store your data in ascii files.

Answer (score 0):

Add some error reporting to your codeand you will get the reason:

```
with open('example.rtf', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in plots:
        try:
            x.append(int(row[0]))
            y.append(int(row[1]))
        except ValueError as ex:
            print ('Oh, NO!! This line is bad: {} - {}'.format(row, ex))
```

Comment: That gives me the same reason

Comment: But what is the message? Lets see the `row` content - it should be printed now

Comment: As commented below the question, there is not "a single line" that is bad, but the complete file format. Compare it to opening a png image with a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

open a notepad and paste your csv file data. which is like as you mention:

1,5 2,3 3,4 4,7 5,4 6,3 7,5 8,7 9,4 10,4

and save it as filename.rtf

and run your code simply

it's fine, the error is because when we open a file  in some applications and after some edit try to save it the application sometimes ask for text format option that make some alter in your data.